# Shipping discount for one shipping method in CartThrob

Tags: cartthrob

Is it possible to have a shipping discount for just one shipping method in CartThrob?

Basically, our client would like to set up Free Shipping Over X, with X being $150 but have the free shipping ONLY apply to UPS Ground shipping (which is $10).

My guess is that this isn't exactly possible. It seems like a workaround would be to use "Amount Off For Orders Over X", however I'm positive that our client won't go for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was all confusing. Turns out all the client needed to do was set the amount that shipping should be free in their shipping settings.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the Cartthrob_discount_free_shipping_over_x. Open it up… find this:

```
        if ($this->core->cart->subtotal() >= $this->core->sanitize_number($this->plugin_settings('order_over')))
    {
        $this->core->cart->set_discounted_shipping(0);
    }
```

change it to this:

```
        if ($this->core->cart->subtotal() >= $this->core->sanitize_number($this->plugin_settings('order_over')))
    {
        if ($this->core->cart->shipping_option() == "YOUR METHOD HERE")
        {
            $this->core->cart->set_discounted_shipping(0);
        }
    }
```

Review some of the other plugins if you feel like adding settings for the shipping option, or want to create a completely new plugin based on that existing one. I suggest putting it in the cartthrob > third_party > discount_plugins folder for ease of maintenance.

Here's some docs related to discount plugin creation: 
http://cartthrob.com/docs/developers/discount_plugins/index.html